# Can the word "there" refer to multiple places?

Tags: word-usage, american-english

Probably a silly question, but can the word "there" refer to more than one place?

Consider the following sentence:

"I visited City A and City B again even though I went there last year."

Can "there" refer to both cities? Or should I use the following instead?

"I visited City A and City B again even though I went to them last year."

Comment: *There* provides a reference to the last-named place. If you wish to refer to multiple places, it's best to use your *them* construction instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that makes a lot of sense. If you post it as an answer, I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: _There_ can easily and naturally refer to both cities, as long as they are presented as a conjoined locative noun phrase, as they are here. Note that _again_ has the same sense of visiting both cities; it's natural to expect _there_ to do likewise.

Comment: See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: The plural in this context and structure would be "**to those places**." HTH.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*There* provides a reference to the last-named place.

> I visited City A and City B again even though I went there last year.

Here the reader understand that *there* refers to City B. If you wish to refer to multiple places, it's best (i.e., less ambiguous) to use your "them" construction instead.

> I visited City A and City B again even though I visited them last year.

Here the pronoun *them* covers the entire list.

Comment: You could also say ‘visited eavh of them, last year’.